# Транспонировать Google таблицу и разложить по заказам

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-forms

Имею таблицу, сформированную из Google Forms:

[image: Таблица с заказами разных товаров]

Хочется сделать из нее что-то типа такого:

[image: Какой хотелось бы результат]

Открыл для себя следующую формулу:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE('Заказы'!1:2); "where Col1 is not null"; 1))}
```

Но, она игнорирует все кроме чисел и выводит только всю таблицу целиком, вот так:

[image: Так не пойдет]

А нужно чтобы каждый заказ был отдельно, и друг за другом или еще как-то так, чтобы это удобно было потом распечатать.

Вот ссылка на [форму](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pcpJ-s9osz1edBogFJdwqACGd5DSwEaHma3tBgn7xY4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Пример бы живой - лень данные забивать в Таблицу

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pcpJ-s9osz1edBogFJdwqACGd5DSwEaHma3tBgn7xY4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @contributorpw вот )

Comment: Да, я видел, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Подчеркну особо, что эта задача **должна** решаться скриптами. Из-за отсутствия порядка данных решение формулами остается лишь возможным в теоретическом плане. Практическое применение потребует больших затрат на сопровождение.

### Введение

> Ради спортивного интереса.

- Можно делить номер строки на количество колонок в карточке, остаток от деления - это будет положение элемента в карточке
- Можно делить номер строки на количество колонок в карточке, целая часть - это будет номер карточки

Условно, для трех карточек в которых по три поля

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Формулы `VLOOKUP` и `HLOOKUP` могут "пробегать" массивы для подстановки по индексам.

Сама задача плохо подходит для формул, поэтому потребуется подготовить данные. Я в примере их просто все привел к строке. Но можно заморочиться.

### Решение

#### Построение заголовков карточек

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(
  MOD(ROW(Подготовленные_данные)-1;COLUMNS(Подготовленные_данные));
  {COLUMN(Подготовленные_данные);Подготовленные_данные};
  2;
  0
))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Построение значений карточек

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP(
  MOD(ROW(Подготовленные_данные)-1;COLUMNS(Подготовленные_данные));
  {COLUMN(Подготовленные_данные);Подготовленные_данные};
  QUOTIENT(ROW(Подготовленные_данные)-1;COLUMNS(Подготовленные_данные))+3;
  0
))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Итоговая формула

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(
  {
    HLOOKUP(
      MOD(ROW(Подготовленные_данные)-1;COLUMNS(Подготовленные_данные));
      {COLUMN(Подготовленные_данные);Подготовленные_данные};
      2;
      0
    )\
    HLOOKUP(
      MOD(ROW(Подготовленные_данные)-1;COLUMNS(Подготовленные_данные));
      {COLUMN(Подготовленные_данные);Подготовленные_данные};
      QUOTIENT(ROW(Подготовленные_данные)-1;COLUMNS(Подготовленные_данные))+3;
      0)
  };
  ""
));"select * where (Col1<>'' and Col2<>'') or(Col1='' and Col2='')")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Сам пример](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11x1Gj967wu7l2jZDpED7BwcGqWID2wAnik6vmavqZOw/edit?usp=sharing)

### Идеи

По идее, можно разбить на колонки, чтобы карточек на единицу площади получалось больше.

Comment: OMG! Спасибо вам огромное за такой развернутый ответ. Я правда мало что понял, как это все работает. Буду изучать.

Comment: Если оно работает, то можно отметить как лучший ответ ;-)

Comment: Размер именованного диапазона по колонкам можно менять. Очень удобно попробуйте задать только первые семь колонок.

Comment: отметил как лучший :) В вашем примере все работает именно так как нужно, правда к себе я так и не смог перенести, моих знаний катастрофически не хватает, чтобы понять что происходит на странице "Результат". Даже читая краткую справку по командам ничего не понятно, и уж тем более где менять количество колонок )) Буду изучать :)

Comment: Не уверен, что формулы это хороший вариант. Обратите внимание, что в Таблице присутствует промежуточный лист расчета (приведение типов) и что есть именованный диапазон, который иногда придется изменять. Эта задача лучше всего решается скриптами. Таблица полностью повторяет ваши данные. Начните с копирования листов в свою Таблицу.